# How to move a servo quickly and without delay function

Tags: servo, code-review, code-optimization

Im trying to move a servo from one place to another while using the typical `for` loop you find in the servo's library example:

```cpp
int lightON = 180;
int lightOFF = 90;

for (pos1 = lightOFF; pos1 <= lightON; pos1 += 1) {
  servo1.write(pos1);
  delay(15);
}

for (pos1 = lightON; pos1 >= lightOFF; pos1 -= 1) {
  servo1.write(pos1);
  delay(15);
}
```

The thing is that while this does work, I want to be able to move the servo a little quicker, but I can't use the `delay()` function because of some connectivity issues with another library (BLYNK).

How could I move the servo from lightOFF to lightON the quickest way possible without using the `delay()` function?

Answer (score 6):

The quickest way possible from `LightON` to `LightOFF` is simply `servo1.write(lightOFF);` without loops or delays, in one go; no need to do it degree by degree. For example:

```cpp
int lightON = 180;
int lightOFF = 90;

for (pos1 = lightOFF; pos1 <= lightON; pos1++) {
  servo1.write(pos1);
  delay(15);
}

servo1.write(lightOFF);
```

If you want it to move a few degrees every loop and do other things in the loop while it moves, you can time it with `millis()` instead of `delay()`. The code below should move the servo 5 degrees every 0.5s:

```cpp
int moveTime = 500; // Move every 0.5s
unsigned long int startMillis = 0;
int position = lightOFF;
int step = 5; // Move 5 degrees

void loop() {
  if (millis() - startMillis >= moveTime) {
    servo1.write(position);
    if (position <= lightON) {
      position = position + step;
    }
    startMillis = millis();
  }
  // Do other things
}
```

Untested and incomplete, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use [map()](https://arduinogetstarted.com/reference/arduino-map) function.

```
void loop() {
  unsigned long progress = millis() - startMillis;

  int angle = map(progress, 0, MOVING_PEDIOD, lightOFF , lightON);
  servo1.write(angle);
}
```

The above code use the [millis()](https://arduinogetstarted.com/reference/arduino-millis) function, therefore you do not need to worry about blocking other code.

Full instruction is available on [How to control speed of servo motor](https://arduinogetstarted.com/faq/how-to-control-speed-of-servo-motor)

Comment: Nice idea! It should be combined with `constrain()` in order to avoid overshooting (`map()` does not implicitly `constrain()`).